# arm-none-eabi-g++: no such file or directory

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-mkr1000

I am trying to upload the "Blink" example to my MKR 1000. However, I keep getting the same error:

> fork/exec /Users/username/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/7-2017q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++: no such file or directory

I have installed the SAMD board from the Board Manager in the IDE, and I also updated GCC-C++ on my machine. I am using a Mac on the Mac Arduino IDE. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Arduino IDE. I tested my MKR 1000 on another computer, and it worked perfectly. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does `/Users/username/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/7-2017q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++` exist?

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for your response. The path does exist, however the file "arm-none-eabi-g++" is not there. I tried to manually download and I put it in there, however it was not able to execute the file.

Comment: This looks like a "How did you install `arm-none-eabi-gcc`?" Whatever script you are calling that is calling `fork/exec /Users/username/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/7-2017q4/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++` got the idea that `arm-none-eabi-g++` lives there. An installer should not result in that problem. The `arm-non-eabi-gcc` package contains both `arm-non-eabi-gcc` and `arm-non-eabi-g++`

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin Do you know how I can install 'arm-non-eabi-gcc'?

Comment: Sure, it depends on what OS you are using, but for just about all LInux distributions, you can simply load pre-built packages for it. You can download generic versions for all OSs at [GNU Toolchain | GNU-RM Downloads](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads).

Comment: the SAMD Arduino boards package installation didn't finish. try to reinstall it by installing a different version in Boards Manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the following folder:

```
/Users/username/Library/Arduino15/packages/arduino
```

And then use the boards manager to reinstall your board package.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (macOS Sonoma 14, Apple silicone) was to install Rosetta 2:

1. Open Terminal (command+Space, search for Terminal)
2. Execute `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`
3. Reopen Arduino IDE